# Can i create a facebook app for facebook page( i mean facebook page support apps)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i never used it so ask that facebook pages support facebook apps. Can i get all info of any facebook-page like we get facebook users info using apps.

i.e-> list of users who like this page today, all users list who like facebook page?

i have three facebook pages from 3 different account. i want to create any facebook app which will give all likes detail new post detail of these page using this app. if page owner once allow then my app can get list any time of users or post of any page who allow my app. is it possible?

Comment: why not take a look at the api functions yourself? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/page

Comment: i will try to do this but first i want to know that is it possible? Cuz i know that we can make a facebook app for get basic detail for facebook user this is possible. but is it possible can we take facebook-app detail?

Comment: If only you actually took a look at the link I gave you..